# Regex to validate an email address

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not expert in JavaScript and need to get this regex to work:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,22}/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Currently this doesn't work fine, even for `myemail@hotmail.com`.

I don't need a new regex, just few changes to this one to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the case-insensitive flag, `i`:

```
var re = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,22}/i;
```

Without this, it would only match upper-case Latin letters, e.g. `MYEMAIL@HOTMAIL.COM`.

See [MDN for a list of supported flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).